# How to determine how much temp tablespace will use my query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have problem with one query that ends with result: "unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP". I optimized it a bit but still I need to check if that optimization is enough. Is there any way to check how much of tablespace it used before and after optimization? Explain Plan tells me that is better now but it won't tell me if information about tablespace unfortunately.

My database is oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the explain plan will show how much TEMP space is estimated to be used, but in my experience, those estimates are sometimes many times higher than what is used.  And there are a lot of factors that will affect how much space will be needed from one execution to the next.  But you can do an `EXPLAIN PLAN` on your various changes and look for the result with little or no TEMP space.  Just beware that even if the plan output does not say it will use TEMP space, it might when actually invoked.

You can use the dbms_xplan package to ask for memory used, if you have the database parameter `pga_aggregate_target` set to a non-zero value:

```
select * from table(
    dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id=>'dwgxfu778vgn8', 
        format=>'allstats, memstats'));
```

Best best is to look for possible ways to eliminate TEMP usage such as no `ORDER BY` clause if possible.  Also, hash-joins can use a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I need information about tablespace cause my company requires it and they are not interested in other information. Even if this will be hard to get it they want it cause numbers are most important for them even if they are not accurate.

Comment: No problem.  A (explain plan's) wild guess may be enough to meet your needs, just do a sanity check on the value.  I've had estimated sort estimates go as high as 90 GB for a 9 GB database!  Reality was much less.  But... if actual usage is huge, time to tune!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help or not but I'm using Toad for Oracle to administer my tablespaces' usage. From there you can see the usage per time and simply extend the size if require.